# How to validate form using HTML, PHP and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to make a form using HTML, PHP, and jQuery AJAX for a website but I don't know how to validate it. Where should I write the code to validate it, in PHP or jQuery?

Comment: Firstly, this question is far too broad. Secondly, you need to write your validation logic in ***both*** JS and PHP. JS is to validate the form for user convenience, the PHP is to validate that the input meets business logic requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using javascript and html than any other language 
The following code is for browser validation

```
<input required> // info
<input required> // more info
<button type="submit">Press to validate</button>
</form>
```

When you click the button the form will be validated

For js validation

```
<button onclick ="myfunction()">Press to validate</button>
<script>
function myfunction(){
var x =document.getElementById('validate');
if (x.value.length < 1){
alert("Empty input box.Form validated")
}
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What is the problem in the answer

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174082/should-can-we-answer-overly-broad-questions-with-overly-broad-answers

Comment: You should ***ALWAYS*** validate on the server-side. Client-side code is easily hacked and bypassed and should only be used as a convenience.